# How to develop/deploy Windows 10 phone application?

Tags: .net, mobile, uwp, windows-10, lumia

I got Lumia Windows 10 phone. And I want to try to develop mobile app for those phone. I have many questions about options in this case:

1. Am i right, there are 3 options: Xamarin (some cross-platform solution for Android/iOS/Windows), .NET (?), UWP ?
2. Can I develop UWP apps for Lumia Windows 10 phone, is UWP supported there?
3. How to deploy app to the phone for testing (can I do it through email/Blootooth/etc) ?
4. What are the options to make app in F#? Is it only Xamarin ? IMHO more preferrable is UWP (will works on next, surface phone too), but seems F# is not supported in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can deploy 8.0 (Silverlight), 8.1 (WinRT) and UWP apps to Windows 10 mobile. With Xamarin you also Build an UWP app, but which includes the shared UI that works on all platforms.
2. Yes, UWP is supported, but only up to [Target Build 15063 (Creators Update), Fall Creators Update Build 16299 is not supported, because Phones don't get the creators update as PC (different branch with less features)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2018/02/14/why-cant-i-deploy-my-uwp-app-with-net-standard-2-0-to-a-mobile-device-or-emulator/).
3. You can deploy the apps via [Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile) or double click it inside file management app on the phone. Since Windows 10 1511 sideloading is enabled by default.